# Обработка формы ввода

Tags: jquery

```
            <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty mt-3 mb-1">
                <label class="control-label">Имя</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
```

Как на JQuery производить мониторинг у объекта с идентификатором **name** у атрибута **name**. И в случае изменений данных в поле ввода выполнять какое-нибудь действие, к примеру `console.info('Данные у объекта изменены');`

**Важно:** Действие нужно выполнять только тогда, когда пользователь закончил ввод данных и покинул форму ввода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('input[name="name"]').on('focusout', function () {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group label-floating is-empty mt-3 mb-1">
  <label class="control-label">Имя</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

Comment: Только сейчас заметил, ответ не выполняет часть задания из вопроса. Он не учитывает были ли изменены данные в форме. Он просто выполняет действие при потери фокуса